# Ethminer Ubuntu 16.04 and Radeon 560

Tags: mining, ethminer

I am trying to get a Radeon 560 with 2GB RAM to work. I searched through everything, tried everything and did several system installs. But I can't get the Radeon 560 to work. With clinfo it also shows me something about OpenCL1.2!? The furthest I came I got an annoying error "No GPU device with sufficient memory was found. Can´t GPU mine. Remove the -G argument. I am very thankful about any hints. KR

Comment: Please provide some examples. Did you install the AMD SDK, OpenCL libraries and amdpro drivers? Also, what miner are you using?

Answer (score 0):

we cannot mine with ≦2GB ram GPU.
buy another above 4GB GPU.